# Cannot access FILES variable inside Bitbake recipe function

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I am trying to write a somewhat generic recipe to add a set of data files to a yocto image.
Since it is generic, my recipe does not know the names of the files until after the fetch and unpack tasks have done their job.  Then, before `do_install`, I can write some bash logic to do a find and create a space-separated list of filenames to be installed in the `${D}` deploy directory and added to `FILES_${PN}`.  Now comes the problem -- it appears that code that I put in a do_xxx shell function cannot see/access/modify `FILES_${PN}`.  And even if I export the
environment variable (let's call it `$FILENAMES`), if I put a statement like `FILES_${PN} += $FILENAMES` in the recipe file but outside of any task functions, that statement cannot see/access the exported `$FILENAMES` environment.

How can I create a function or something in which my dynamically created `$FILENAMES` environment variable and the bitbake `FILES_${PN}` variable are both "in scope" at the same time?  Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the issue, can you provide your recipe content ? I can help you more with that

Comment: what's the need of updating FILES_* variable? are you planning to add those in different packages? If not, would recommend having a `generic` bash logic in `do_unpack_append` to install those in ${D}.

Comment: Also AFAIK, the FILES* variable are processed at the recipe parsing stage, and any update to those after may not be entertained by bitbake.